# PHP combine like arrays based on a duplicate key VALUE not just the key iteself

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array that looks like the below (this is a print_r on a $data variable)

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [quan] => 1
            [prod_key] => 6f2e8858b8333afaeec8cd51be30ba6a
            [title] => Broomhandle - 6" x 12.5"
            [total] => 11.00
            [weight] => 0.25
            [image] => thumb_37658989fcd29e9.jpg
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [quan] => 1
            [prod_key] => 6f2e8858b8333afaeec8cd51be30ba6a
            [title] => Broomhandle - 6" x 12.5"
            [total] => 11.00
            [weight] => 0.25
            [image] => thumb_37658989fcd29e9.jpg
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [quan] => 1
            [prod_key] => of2ef85vb8333afaeec8cd51be30jq7i
            [title] => Watch
            [total] => 65.00
            [weight] => 0.15
            [image] => thumb_37658989fcd29e9.jpg
        )
)
```

What I am trying to do is loop through the array and combine the items that have the same prod_key into one item and update the the total, quantity and weight so the above example should look like:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [quan] => 2
            [prod_key] => 6f2e8858b8333afaeec8cd51be30ba6a
            [title] => Broomhandle - 6" x 12.5"
            [total] => 22.00
            [weight] => 0.50
            [image] => thumb_37658989fcd29e9.jpg
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [quan] => 1
            [prod_key] => of2ef85vb8333afaeec8cd51be30jq7i
            [title] => Watch
            [total] => 65.00
            [weight] => 0.15
            [image] => thumb_37658989fcd29e9.jpg
        )
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

make a new array and use the product key as an array indice. Then you can easily add or update the entries

```
$result = array();
foreach ($data as $v) {
    if (!isset($result[$v['prod_key']])) {
        $result[$v['prod_key']] = $v;
    } else {
    $result[$v['prod_key']]['quan'] += $v['quan'];
    $result[$v['prod_key']]['total'] += $v['total'];
    $result[$v['prod_key']]['weight'] += $v['weight'];
        //etc...
    }
}
```